# Refresh view content when there is change in database laravel

Tags: laravel

I am using laravel queue to upload a csv file. And, I have used a column `completed` on the database table.

So, by default the value of this column will be `0` and as soon as the job is completed this column's value will be updated to `1` for that particular row.
Similarly, during uploading phase, this value will be `2` and if some error occured during upload or if some row can't be imported then the value will be `3`

On front end, I have a simple button like:

```
@if($r->completed == 1)
    <a class="btn btn-xs btn-primary d-inline-block" href="{{url('/?property='.$r->id)}}">Property</a>
@elseif($r->completed == 2)
    <a class="btn btn-xs btn-warning d-inline-block" href="#">Pending</a>
@elseif($r->completed == 3)
    <a class="btn btn-xs btn-secondary d-inline-block" href="{{route('property.create',$r->id)}}">Par. Completed</a>
@else
    <a class="btn btn-xs btn-secondary d-inline-block" href="{{route('property.create',$r->id)}}">Property</a>
@endif
```

Yeah, its working totally fine. Here, we need to refresh to check the recent status. However, my requirement is to update the status without refreshing the page.

After some searching, I find that sending ajax request on certain interval might be an option. However, it don't seems ideal, so I don't want to go with that.

Is there any better option available? Currently, I am using jquery/javascript (not any js framework like vue,react).

Comment: If you aren't using any front end frameworks such as `Angular`, `Vue js`, `React`, then you can definitely stick to `jQuery`. With `jQuery`, you can make   `ajax` requests, and update the page without reloads based on the returned response. Please elaborate on why it doesn't seem ideal to you and maybe I can help explain a little better.

Comment: It can be solved ideally using `websockets`. You can try `Pusher` or `PubNub`.

Comment: As @The_ehT said you can use websockets. You can try Pusher. You can see how to implement pusher in server end and client end over here. https://pusher.com/docs/channels/getting_started/javascript